# How to disable ag-grid sidebar options

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using Ag-grid sidebar and wanted to display all the columns as options to check or uncheck but have some be read-only. I dont have any groups of data.
I've been looking through the documentation and it says I need to set `functionsReadOnly` to tru but that doesnt work

It seems I have to set `pivotMode:true` but doing so makes all the columns on the grid disappear
I want all my columns to show but just have some of the options in the sidebar as disabled.
Here is my code

`config.js`

```
 { columnDefs: [
    {
      headerName: 'ColA',
      field: 'colA',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'ColB',
      field: 'colB'
      enablePivot: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'uploadedFiles.fileFormat',
      field: 'formatDescription'
    },
    {
      headerName: 'ColC',
      field: 'colC',
    }
    
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    sortable: true,
    suppressMenu: false,
    resizable: true,
    suppressColumnsToolPanel: false
  },
  rowSelection: 'single',
  sideBar: {
    toolPanels: [
      {
        id: 'columns',
        labelDefault: 'Columns',
        toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
        toolPanelParams: {
          suppressRowGroups: true,
          suppressValues: true,
          suppressPivots: true,
          suppressPivotMode: true,
          suppressSideButtons: true
        }
      }
    ],
    hiddenByDefault: true
  },
  pivotMode:true
}
```

I want all these columns to show on the grid and the all the options to show in the sidebar...I just want to disable colB but enabling pivot mode makes all the columns disappear on the grid and just using `functionsReadOnly` on colB doesnt do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a custom class to that particular column's tool panel using `toolPanelClass: 'some-class'` and use css `pointer-event: none`

or you can use `document.getElementByClassName('some-class')` and manipulate the DOM as per your requirement.

https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/tool-panel-columns/#example-styling

Comment: This works but it doesnt work for the toggle select all functionality. anyway around this?

Comment: Well, a simple workaround would be to remove `select / unselect All` by using `suppressColumnSelectAll`.

Comment: Yeah, I need the functionality, I just want it to no unselect the ones that ive added the class with the `pointer-events:none`

Comment: Okay, so I managed a workaround. Create an array with all the `colId/field` whose checkboxes were disabled. Add `(columnVisible)` event in your grid. Use `setColumnVisible(colKey, visible)` to set visibility. In their documentation, this accepts only 2 params but in stackblitz it was asking for 3 params so I set it as null. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-multi-auto-column-group-wfytcx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts